# using window.location.href to point to javascript enabled page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a personal website.So,its a very lightweight website!

The website uses `jquery` heavily.So if target browser doesn't have `javascript` enabled,my website would not work.
To resolve this issue I used this html

```
<html>

<head>

<script>
window.location.href="javascriptEnabled.html";
/*Since javascript is enabled redirect to javascript based page*/
</script>

</head>

<body>
Showing Static Website since javascript is not enabled..
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see,I am redirecting to `javascript` enabled page if the target browser supports it.

But if `javascript` is not enabled,the script would not work and then static html would be loaded which is in `body` tag!

I have two questions.

1>Is this the best way to resolve `javacript-no javascript issue` browser issue?

2>If I use `window.location.href` and the browser is `javascript` enabled,would it download the full page or would it stop at `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To keep things simple, yes it's an OK idea. You can load content with `<noscript>` tags
2. As soon as the browser hits that `window.location.href` it will start redirecting, but it will still download all DOM. Browsers download all Document then it will start to render.

   You can use: `<body onload="document.body.style.display = 'none';">` to hide it's contents until redirect occurs.

Comment: 1)If Browser is not JS Compatible then It will not excute the script else it works the same. So no big Differnce.
2) NO, if you use window.location.href then It will start excuting the script untill it loads DOM

Comment: `<noscript>` is not optimal to use. The browser can have javascript enabled, but all scripts could have been removed in some filter.